# Dynamic result columns using Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having following data in Neo4j graph dB:

`Year        Fruit           Count
2006        Apple           10
2006        Mango           15
2006        Banana          30
2007        Apple           13
2007        Mango           11
2007        Banana          27
2008        Apple           2
2008        Mango           23
2008        Banana          47`

I am interested in getting following result:

`Year        Apple       Banana      Mango
2006        10          30              15
2007        13          27              11
2008        2           47              23`

How can I get this result using Neo4j Cypher query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to SQL the result columns are fixed (except when you use `RETURN *`).

The closest you could do is to create a map and return the map.

```
RETURN year, { banana: case fruit when "banana" then count else null end, 
               apple: case fruit when "apple" then count else null end, 
               mango: case fruit when "mango" then count else null end} as data
```

with the [apoc library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) you can generalize that:

`RETURN year, apoc.map.fromPairs(collect([fruit, count])) as data`